# Apache X-Forward-For on https

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php5

I have a load balancing IP in front of 2 apache servers

On the backend servers I'm using Apache 2.4 with mod_remoteip enabled to retrieve the real client IP which is working so long as the request is sent over HTTP, if a request is sent over HTTPS the 'X-Forward-For' is omitted

Is there a way to easily retrieve this?

First thought is to get all requests over HTTP and then forward to HTTPS with the hope of preserving that header

LogFormat being used - `LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined`

Comment: please, can you tell us, what kind of loadbalancer?

Comment: It's a loadbalance IP purchased from OVH (https://www.ovh.co.uk/solutions/ip-load-balancing/) so I don't really have control over the setup of the actual loadbalancer.

Answer (score 0):

X-Forwarded-For is a request header so it's upt to the client connecting to add that header or not to the request.

Apache itself can add that header in a request if it acts a proxy.

So, if the header is not there, the original request does not include the header.

Comment: I don't have control over the actual loadbalancer unfortunately. Would it be possible to direct everyone to port 80 and then redirect them to 443 including this X-Forwarded-For header?

Comment: I don't think so.